# How to set up navigation on electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have tried navigating through pages on electron but it throws an error. It throws error cant navigate through local files. What is the efficient way to do so? I am developing an ERP system for manufacturing clothes. It has multiple modules. What would be efficient way to do so?

I am getting following error. On clicking link anchor tag. Tried `window.location`. But issue remains the same:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/InventoryManagementModule/electroboost/electron-boilerplate/app/InventoryMangementModule/Dashboard.html

Comment: I have the same issue. I could not find the solution.